# Convergence of this series which gives no result in root test

Tags: real-analysis

Is the series whose general term is $$\frac{\tan \frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt n}$$ convergent? I have tried for root test but the limit is 1 so no decision taken. How to check for convergence of this series?

Comment: Use  the Limit Comparison Test, with $\sum 1/n^{3/2}$ (for small $x$, $\tan x\approx x$).

Comment: sorry my question was not that "edit" changes it. tan (1/n) is in numerator

Comment: now it is ok....

Comment: now help me to decide the convergence of the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that
$$
\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)},
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}=1\cdot\frac{1}{1}=1,
$$
since $\frac{1}{n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Using this, you can prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ \frac{\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\ }{\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}}=1.
$$
In light of this, the Limit Comparison Test tells us that the two series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$
have the same convergence behavior.

Comment: Is the 2n limit 1??? I think it is 0

Comment: @nothingobvious Woops, found a typo.  Take a look at it now.

Comment: how can you say that limt is 1 still please check again ...now it is $\infty$

Comment: @nothingobvious Nope.  It is correct now.

Comment: sorry...now it is ok...

Answer (score 2):

$\tan(x)$ is convex on $(0,\pi/2)$ and so we know that on $[0,\pi/4]$
$$
|\tan(x)|\le\frac4\pi|x|
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{\tan\left(\frac1n\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\le\frac4\pi\frac1{n^{3/2}}
$$
and use the p-test.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 3$ (to get into the first quadrant),

$\tan(1/n) = \dfrac{\sin(2/n)}{1+\cos(2/n)} \le \sin(2/n) \le 2/n$

Hence

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{\tan(1/n)}{\sqrt{n}} \le  \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{n^{3/2}}$